# How to stop cron jobs created by "whenever" gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rubygems, whenever

I'm using the "whenever" gem and got it working by doing:

```
whenever --set environment=production --update-crontab theCronJob
```

The interval I'm using is 2 minutes since I'm still trying to figure it out. However, now I get a You have mail message in my terminal window every 2 minutes. I guess the cron runs and lets me know about it. How do I stop my cron from running? These messages are starting to pile up.

Thank you

Comment: hi AdamT how to run this cron job?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To delete the auto-generated cronjobs from your crontab, run `whenever` against your defintion file with the `-c` flag:

```
$ whenever -c theCronJob
```

Alternatively, open your crontab...

```
$ crontab -e
```

... and then manually delete the undesired entries.

Answer (score 4):

following will delete the scheduled crontab:

```
crontab -r
```