# How do I completely stop the Whenever Cron job?

Tags: ruby, cron

How do I completely stop a cron job from running on my Macbook? I had set one up to play around and test CronJobs but don't know how to stop it.

This is my runner.rb file:

```
class Runner

  def run
    puts "This is a cron test"
  end

end
```

This is my schedule.rb file:

```
set :output, "./cron_log.log"

every 2.minutes do
  runner "Runner.run"
end
```

And This is my deploy.rb file:

```
after "deploy:symlink", "deploy:update_crontab"

namespace :deploy do
  desc "do cron job test"
  task :update_crontab, :roles => :db do
    run "cd #{release_path} && whenever --update-crontab #{application}"
  end
end
```

For reference, I found this stackoverflow response that provides info on deleting the autogenerated cronjobs from my crontab, but it doesn't seem to help me stop it altogether. Plus I'm not sure what my 'definition file' is.
[How to stop cron jobs created by "whenever" gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525891/how-to-stop-cron-jobs-created-by-whenever-gem)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just enter  crontab -r   to delete the cron job.